# The indicator does not move to a separate panel (Tradingview study error)

Tags: plot, pine-script, overlay, show, indicator

have basic account, maybe that's the problem :)
if you leave the function as an "indicator", Awesome Oscilator is overlaid on the chart, rather than located in a separate panel
writing function overlay=false
or its absence in the code, leaves the AO on the main graph

Comment: //@version=5
indicator("Fractals + Alligator + Divergent Bars + Squat Bars + Awesome Oscillator + BTCUSD", shorttitle="Bill Williams all",overlay=true)

showAwesomeOscillator= input.bool(defval=false, title="Awesome Oscillator", group="Awesome Oscillator")

ao = ta.sma(hl2,5) - ta.sma(hl2,34)
aoColor = ao >= 0 ? (ao[1] < ao ? #26A69A : #B2DFDB) : (ao[1] < ao ? #FFCDD2 : #EF5350)
plot(ao, style=plot.style_columns, color=aoColor, transp=0)

Comment: Please provide some context. What is the programming language? Which libraries/framework are you using? What is the project context? What is the intended behaviour? What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `overlay` is set to `true` in the code that you shared in the comments. So, change it to `false`.

Whenever you make changes to the `overlay` argument, you need to remove your indicator from your chart and add it again for the changes to take effect.

Comment: in this case all indicators appear on a separate panel )))

Comment: if overlay=true or default, then all indicators appear in a separate panel and you can only transfer the whole group to the main chart.